# How do I programmatically scroll a winforms datagridview control?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, scroll

I'm implementing some drag drop features in one my controls inheriting from a datagridview. Basically I'm dragging a row from somewhere in the DGV and dropping it somewhere else, reordering the rows. I've run into a problem though. If the DGV is too large such that there's a scrollbar, how can I have the DGV scroll up or down while the user is in the middle of a dragdrop?

I know how to get the current mouse position and also get the position of the dgv rectangle and such. So, I can easily find out if i'm in the top or bottom half of the rectangle... I just need a way to programmatically scroll the dgv. I'd prefer if I don't have to keep changing the selected cell to do this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Isaac

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Well, since this is a datagridview... Sorry for the 'winforms' in the question... but I could just do this.. scrolling up or down one row.

Scroll up:

```
this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex - 1
```

Scroll Down:

```
this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex + 1;
```

You've gotta make sure to check that the numbers don't go out of bounds though.

Comment: when there are lots of hidden row( "row[i].visible = false") . this will not work.  row+1, -1 will direct to invisible row which will do nothing!!

Answer (score 13):

you can do this by setting `HorizontalScrollingOffset` / `VerticalScrollingOffset` of the `DataGridView`

to set HorizontalScrollingOffset

```
dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset = dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset + 10;
```

check

[DataGridView.HorizontalScrollingOffset Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.horizontalscrollingoffset.aspx)

and

for `VerticalScrollingOffset` you can use Reflection

include namespace `System.Reflection`

```
PropertyInfo verticalOffset = dataGridView1.GetType().GetProperty("VerticalOffset", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            verticalOffset.SetValue(this.dataGridView1, 10, null);
```

Comment: VerticalScrollingOffset have read only property.. So you can only `get` it, can't `set` it.

Comment: Not both, Horizontal is {get; set;} Although it will not help him in a way or another

Comment: o didnt notice that... so for VerticalScrollingOffset you can user reflection... edited my code....

Comment: Wow, I didn't know you could use reflection to get around read only properties. This actually scrolls the control. Thanks a bunch for this!

Comment: This only seems to scroll it up. How do I make it scroll down?

Comment: you will get the value of the VerticalOffset using GetValue. you just need to increment of decrement the value from that.

Comment: for a large dataGrid, this works but seems to stuff up the ordering of data i the dataGrid - I'd suggest it is readOnly for a reason.
The answer from @IsaacBolinger works for me

Comment: It's and old topic but big thanks for the reflection trick. Setting FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex isn't enough. It always brings selected row to the top of the grid and doesn't keep its original exact position. So when I refresh the grid everything jump which will make the user confused as hell. I browsed the internet for the good solution and there were dozens of useless advices. You are the first man with a good, working solution. Cheers!

Comment: You save my 100 days mate, it takes me 5 days to found this awsome answer :x

Answer (score 6):

```
dgv.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dgv.RowCount - 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

You may do that using WinAPI by sending message to the control telling it to scroll up or down.

Here is the code, I hope it helps:

```
private const int WM_SCROLL = 276; // Horizontal scroll
private const int WM_VSCROLL = 277; // Vertical scroll
private const int SB_LINEUP = 0; // Scrolls one line up
private const int SB_LINELEFT = 0;// Scrolls one cell left
private const int SB_LINEDOWN = 1; // Scrolls one line down
private const int SB_LINERIGHT = 1;// Scrolls one cell right
private const int SB_PAGEUP = 2; // Scrolls one page up
private const int SB_PAGELEFT = 2;// Scrolls one page left
private const int SB_PAGEDOWN = 3; // Scrolls one page down
private const int SB_PAGERIGTH = 3; // Scrolls one page right
private const int SB_PAGETOP = 6; // Scrolls to the upper left
private const int SB_LEFT = 6; // Scrolls to the left
private const int SB_PAGEBOTTOM = 7; // Scrolls to the upper right
private const int SB_RIGHT = 7; // Scrolls to the right
private const int SB_ENDSCROLL = 8; // Ends scroll

[DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg,IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Now assuming you have a textbox control on your form. You can move it with:

```
SendMessage(textBox1.Handle,WM_VSCROLL,(IntPtr)SB_PAGEUP,IntPtr.Zero); //ScrollUp
SendMessage(textBox1.Handle,WM_VSCROLL,(IntPtr)SB_PAGEDOWN,IntPtr.Zero); //ScrollDown
```

If that classic general solution doesn't work for you. You may want to look at [FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx) Property and change it regarding your mouse position during dragging.

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't tried it.. the guy above you has a non winapi way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the DragOver event.  Check if the mouse is located close to the top or the bottom of the control (use PointToClient).  When it is, enable a timer with an interval of ~200 msec.  In the Tick event handler scroll the DGV by a row.  Disable the timer when the mouse isn't close and after DoDragDrop returns.  The user can now easily and intuitively scroll the grid just be hovering near the ends.

Comment: Yeah I just need to figure out how to scroll it by a row!

Comment: Ah, the gentleman below has the solution. I already have dragover implemented, I will add some code in there to make it scroll intelligently much like you suggested. Thanks for your design advice Hans.

Comment: Actually this works well even without the timer! Seems like the movement of the grid rows beneath the mouse is sufficient to keep firing the DragOver event.

Answer (score 0):

Answer using MaxEcho's answer as a base.  You can override the OnScroll event of the DataGridView.   The eventArgs in this method contain the first visible line number.  You can pass this line number to the other DataGridView, and set the FirstDisplayedScrollRowIndex to cause it to scroll to that position.

The only issue is somewhat cosmetic, if you scroll quite fast, the second datagridview pauses updating/animating and blinks to the active line once your scrolling slows.

```
class DGVSubclass : DataGridView
{    

    public Action<ScrollEventArgs> delOnScroll;
    ....

    protected override void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnScroll(e);


        if (e.ScrollOrientation == ScrollOrientation.VerticalScroll && 
            delOnScroll != null)
            delOnScroll.Invoke(e);

    }

    public void setSrcoll(ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        //ScrollEventArgs.NewValue is a line number
        this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = e.NewValue;
    }

    public void bindScroll(DGV3_Broker dgv)
    {
        delOnScroll = dgv.setSrcoll;          
    }
}

dgvTwo.bindScroll(dgvOne);  //DGVTwo Scrollbar controls both,
```