# C# scroll a datagrid with two button (up-down), not with scrollbar

Tags: c#, datagrid

should I change the scrollbar in a datagrid with two buttons (for a touchscreen device), how can I do in c #? I do not know the code to insert the event click the button. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to manipulate the `FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex` by adding or subtracting the appropriate amount of rows on each click.

[msdn FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link it will may help you
[programaticaly scroll in windows form controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766409/how-do-i-programmatically-scroll-a-winforms-control)
To scroll programatically you need to set FirstDisplayedScrollingIndex. 
ex: Lets say datagrid view displays 10 rows. you need to display another 10 rows

```
if(datagridview1.Rows.Count>=scrollingindex && scrollingindex>1)
{dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = scrollingindex;
dataGridView1.Rows[scrollingindex].Selected=true
}scrollingindex+=10;
```

The above code is for scroll down. Similarly you can do it for scroll up.

Comment: can you give me an example for "scroll up"?

Comment: if you want scroll up then decrease scroll index. Every thing remains same

Comment: can you write an example? because if i decrease index it doesn't work fine