# Shift + mouse wheel horizontal scrolling

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

The use of shift + scroll wheel is fairly common for horizontal scrolling.

Both of those are fairly easy to capture. I can use the MouseWheel event with a flag set by the KeyDown, KeyUp events to keep track of when the shift key is pressed.

However, how do I actually trigger the horizontal scrolling? I am aware of WM_MOUSEHWHEEL, can that be used to trigger the event?

Update:
For a `System.Windows.Form` there is a `HorizontalScroll` property that is of type `HScrollProperties`. You can manipulate the `Value` attribute on that object to change the horizontal scrollbar's position. However, so far I haven't spotted any other controls on which that object is available.

Comment: Great question, I've been wanting to know this as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are creating your own control derived from `UserControl` or `ScrollControl` or `Form`, you can use this simple solution:

```
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.VScroll && (Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Shift) == Keys.Shift)
    {
        this.VScroll = false;
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
        this.VScroll = true;
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
    }
}
```

### Explanation

If a control has `AutoScroll` and is displaying scrollbars, when you scroll the mouse wheel you will get the following behaviour:

1. If no scrollbars are enabled, it does nothing.
2. If only vertical scrollbar is enabled, it scrolls vertical scrollbar.
3. If only horizontal scrollbar is enabled, it scrolls horizontal scrollbar.
4. If both vertical and horizontal scrollbars are enabled, it scrolls vertical scrollbar.

Noticing this behaviour, I figured out this hack to override `OnMouseWheel` of the control, then if the vertical scrollbar is enabled and <kbd>Shift</kbd> is held down, it disables the vertical scrollbar before calling `base.OnMouseWheel`. This will trick the control in scrolling the horizontal scrollbar (behaviour 3 as shown above).

Comment: I haven't tested this, but if it works, this is the way to go.

Comment: @ChristopherHarris Yes, it works *under Windows*. Not sure if it works under Linux (Mono) (but using P/Invoke will definitely fail anyway.) Though, this solution is quite hacky indeed.

Comment: I wouldn't say this solution is hacky. You're altering the default behavior of an event based on some external criteria. Your code directly reflects that, and does so without relying on proprietary dlls. I would say that the WindowsForms classes are providing you a hacky, heavily state-manipulation driven api, but that your code is using it in the best way possible for this specific scenario.

Answer (score 4):

In your designer file, you'll need to manually add a MouseWheel event delegate.

```
this.richTextBox.MouseWheel += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.RichTextBox_MouseWheel);
```

Then, in your code behind, you can add the following.

```
private const int WM_SCROLL = 276; // Horizontal scroll 
private const int SB_LINELEFT = 0; // Scrolls one cell left 
private const int SB_LINERIGHT = 1; // Scrolls one line right

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int wMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam); 

private void RichTextBox_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Shift)
    {
        var direction = e.Delta > 0 ? SB_LINELEFT : SB_LINERIGHT;

        SendMessage(this.richTextBox.Handle, WM_SCROLL, (IntPtr)direction, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

For more information on the const values, see the following SO:  [How do I programmatically scroll a winforms datagridview control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766409/how-do-i-programmatically-scroll-a-winforms-control)

### UPDATE

Use [Alvin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828121/shift-mouse-wheel-horizontal-scrolling/11218920#11218920) if possible. It's ***way better***.

Comment: This works, but causes the scroll to only nudge the scrollbar, instead of thunking (yes that is a technical term ;)) it like the wheel would normally. @Alvin Wong's hacky solution works perfectly.

Comment: Na, I would *totally* use Alvin's (assuming it works). It's *way* cleaner and it's not using external methods or consts, etc. I would highly suggest the OP change the answer to Alvin's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The same code as provided by xixonia in VB.NET

```
Private Const WM_SCROLL As Integer = 276 
Private Const SB_LINELEFT As Integer = 0 
Private Const SB_LINERIGHT As Integer = 1

<DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, 
                                    wMsg As UInteger,
                                    wParam As IntPtr, 
                                    lParam As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Private Sub RichTextBox_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.MouseWheel

  If ModifierKeys = Keys.Shift Then
    Dim direction = If(e.Delta > 0, SB_LINELEFT, SB_LINERIGHT)
    SendMessage(Me.RichTextBox1.Handle, WM_SCROLL, CType(direction, IntPtr), IntPtr.Zero)
  End If
End Sub
```