# is tilt wheel unavailable on linux under mono?

Tags: c#, mono

I am porting an app from windows to linux and it appears no horizontal wheel mouse messages are appearing at the overridden C# wndproc method. Can any one confirm that Mono doesn't provide theses messages or if I must do something extra under Mono?

Comment: See the comment by Alvin on this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11218920/945456)