# Pressing this button programmatically

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, window, scrollbar

Is there a method to pressing this button using programming code?
[image]

I can't seem to think of a method so I was wondering whether anyone else here has come up with one.

Comment: If it's a DGV there... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766409/how-do-i-programmatically-scroll-a-winforms-control

Comment: for future reference, `this button` is called the scroll thumb.  most controls have a `method` to scroll the controls.  Buttons and other widgets are for users to press, click and fiddle with.

Comment: What if it is a list box @PGallagher

Comment: Gotta love XY questions.  If you are trying to make a lower item scroll into view, try the `TopIndex` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Dot Net 4.5 Winforms ListBox;

Scroll Down;

```
If lstListBox.Topindex < lstListBox.Items.Count - 1 Then

    lstListBox.Topindex += 1

End If
```

Scroll Up;

```
If lstListBox.Topindex > 0 Then

    lstListBox.Topindex -= 1

End If
```

Comment: `TopIndex` will make sure the indicated item is visible without changing the selection.

Comment: Quite right Plutonix... @User2177940... Simply replace `SelectedIndex`with `TopIndex` if you don't want to change the selection...

Comment: Is there no direct way of just simulating the press of that button? I don't want it to lose its selected item and by using this code it loses the selected item.

Comment: See my comment above, I've also adjusted my answer ;-)