# Programmatically Scroll GridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a Windows Form application where once someone scans a barcode, details will show up in the GridView. When the GridView fills up the screen, I would like the grid to automatically scroll to the very **bottom** so user's won't have to scroll manually.

I've tried the method in the following article: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q344790/gridview-scroll-to-bottom-automatically
However, the GridView.MakeRowVisible method did not work.

The gridView1.MoveLast() also did not work, and I receive no errors or exceptions.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I tried that method as well but it hadn't worked. I do believe I overlooked that RefreshDataSource() was resetting my view, though.

Answer (score 0):

For Scroll Up and Down Use this:-

Scroll up:

```
this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex - 1
```

Scroll Down:

```
this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = this.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex + 1;
```

Please see this [Refrenece](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766409/how-do-i-programmatically-scroll-a-winforms-datagridview-control/4773030#4773030)